# Reusing KeyDown event multiple times

Tags: c#

## What do I want to achieve?

I want to be able to close a form by pressing the ESC button and reuse as many code as possible.

## Actually working code

I have the following code that exactly does what I want:

```
public static void Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Form form = (Form)sender;

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        form.Close();
    }
}
```

The problem with it is, that I have to copy it into every form of my project.

## Which additional functionality do I want?

I don't want to have to copy the code to every form, but Instead reuse the code all the time.

## What have I tried so fare

I tried to add the same event (KeyDown) to every form and it also compiles without problems.
But when pressing ESC nothing happens.

### In the form

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.AllowEscape(true);
}
```

### In the HelperClass

```
public static class FormHelper
{
    public static void AllowEscape(this Form form, bool allow = true)
    {
        if (allow == true) form.KeyDown += FormHelper.Form_KeyDown; else form.KeyDown -= FormHelper.Form_KeyDown;
    }
    
    public static void Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Form form = (Form)sender;
    
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            form.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: Set the [`Form.KeyPreview`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview?view=netframework-4.7.2&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Form.KeyPreview)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.7.2)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) property to `true`.

Comment: @dr.null aah, that's what I was missing. Now it works this way. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks fine and should work. 
Although I would recommend to create kind of a base class for managing the escape button and closing the form.
The class can looks like:

```
public class EscForm : Form
{
    public EscForm()
    {
        KeyDown += EscForm_KeyDown;
    }

    private void EscForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Form form = (Form)sender;

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            form.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Then any form inheriting from `EscForm` like `public partial class MyForm : EscForm` will support closing the form with the Escape button.

Comment: Perfect, this is even better than my original attempt! Thanks a lot!